# What is this RPGA world/campaign design contest winner (ca. 2006?) I remember?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, product-identification

More than a decade ago, my best friend had an online subscription to various D&D materials. When he was back home visiting, he let me spend a few hours exploring this treasure trove. From what I can remember, there were fully indexed, digital versions of the current rule books. There were Q&A and discussion fora as well as online campaign settings somewhat like much older/slower play-by-mail. One of the campaign worlds I was particularly impressed with there was essentially a water world, where adventures took place on the high seas between islands and underwater in the deep.

What struck me the most, though, was the world design contest winner from an RPGA network contest that I had found in the campaign settings. As I recall, it was set on a world where the great heroes had just failed to prevent the invasion of some extra-planar entities that meant to take total control. Completely blown away by the unusual concept of the starting point, I had noted the name of this world and campaign setting but lost it over the years. My friend could not remember it and no longer had his subscription. I would very much like to relearn the name of this world and get more details about it as a campaign setting. Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Just to be make sure: The water-world you mention is *not* the world design contest winner you're looking for, correct? If so, you may want to cut some of the tangential information, it's distracting. Also, can you remember *anything* else? What year the contest was held (The RPGA Net ran many design contests, and took submissions for tournaments), or what book/magazine mentioned it? Is 2006 when you saw it, or when it was made?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Jason_c_o. While I realised the superfluous details could be distracting, they also provided a context I thought might help.

No, the water world campaign is not the one about which I was asking (though I wouldn't mind learning its name and more about it, too).

It was the WoC subscription service with all the manuals, rulebooks, campaign settings and adventures that mentioned the invaded world setting.

I recall my friend's visit as being in late summer 2006, the time at which I saw the invaded world campaign: it had already won an RPGA world design contest.

Comment: Notably, the winner of the 2002 RPGA contest was Eberron, which is still a major campaign setting published by Wizards of the Coast. Definitely doesn’t match this description, but so far as I know, that was the only contest of the sort that Wizards held—certainly the only one that resulted in publication of the setting that won. Is it possible that this was runner-up or honorable mention or something from that contest?

Comment: Looking into this more, it seems that WotC went out of their way to *not* discuss the non-winning entries to that contest. Of the three finalists, only Eberron is known since the rules of the contest included the rights to all finalist submissions becoming property of Wizards of the Coast and the authors signing NDAs about them. We know that Rich Burlew (of _Order of the Stick_ fame) was one and Nathan Toomey was the other, but nothing about what they wrote. Of the semi-finalists, 5/8 have been published elsewhere, and the other 3/8 are unknown. Investigating those 5.

Comment: @KRyan Hoping your research is productive

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It wasn’t, sadly, which is why I didn’t put an answer on this.

Comment: The subscription service could be DnD Insider? That however only existed from about 2009 onwards https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/193504/when-did-the-dungeons-and-dragons-insider-exist